# Posting to Yii PHP framework using Backbone.js

Tags: post, backbone.js, yii, xmlhttprequest, csrf

I am trying to use Backbone.js models to save to my Yii web application but I am getting a "The CSRF token could not be verified" response even when the model is a serialized form and I use Backbone.sync to set a header.

The model (the form has the CSRF token in it and sends it as a "YII_CSRF_TOKEN" attribute):

```
var v = new ModelName ($('.formclass').serializeJSON());
```

JSON serializer:

```
 //form.serializeJSON
 (function( $ ){
 $.fn.serializeJSON=function() {
 var json = {};
 jQuery.map($(this).serializeArray(), function(n, i){
 json[n['name']] = n['value'];
 });
 return json;
 };
 })( jQuery );
```

The backbone.sync:

```
Backbone.old_sync = Backbone.sync;
     Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
     var new_options =  _.extend({
         beforeSend: function(xhr) {
             console.log('backbone sync');
             var token = model.get('X_CSRF_TOKEN');
             console.log('token ='+token)
             if (token) xhr.setRequestHeader('YII_CSRF_TOKEN', token);
         }
     }, options)
        Backbone.old_sync(method, model, new_options);
 };
```

I have also tried setting the header as 'X_CSRF_TOKEN', to no avail.

Comment: Does it work fine with non-xhr POST-request?

Answer (score 0):

**YII_CSRF_TOKEN** is not a header, it is just a form value.
According to [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php#L967) line our request have to contain

- a CSRF cookie, it is already set by first, non-XHR page load
- the form data value named **YII_CSRF_TOKEN**

Answer (score 0):

If you send your data with save() you must send cookies and session id in parameters. See here a cached version of this blog post (cuz its offline now): http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tML1kmL08ikJ:blog.opperator.com/post/15671431847/backbone-js-sessions-and-authentication+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on localhost, you might need to setup a Virtual Host to be able to perform cookie authentication as stated in this thread:[this thread](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/26901-csrf-validation/page__p__129470__hl__enable+c+rf#entry129470)

IE and Chrome does not accept cookies from localhost so that could be the reason